# Type mismatch when trying to pass array inside function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am having trouble passing array into fuction

```
void funkcia_e( int *pole_cien[], int* dlzka_pola_cien, bool v_bolo_vykonane ) {
    some_other_function(v_bolo_vykonane);
    //work with pole_cien[i], malloc etc
}

void main() {
    bool v_bolo_vykonane = false;
    int dlzka_pola_cien = 0;
    float pole_cien[1]; //make quasi-empty array

    funkcia_e(&pole_cien[0], &dlzka_pola_cien, v_bolo_vykonane);
}
```

But IDE is throwing error when trying to compile this:

```
Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "float *" is incompatible with parameter of type "int **"  135 
Error   C2664   'void funkcia_e(int *[],int *,bool)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'float *' to 'int *[]'
```

anyone can share some knowledge on what I am doing wrong?

I am trying to pass a pointer to array, size of array and a bool variable into funkcia_e.

Inside funkcia_e I will modify the contents of the array (realloc, fill with values) , size of array integer and then work with those new values in main.

Comment: Where do you create `pole_cien`, `dlzka_pola_cien` and `v_bolo_vykonane` ? What's their types?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your error stems from the fact that you declare `int *pole_cien[]` which is a double pointer. The address of the array "pole_cien" is either `pole_cien[]` or `*pole_cien`, but not both.

Comment: Can't do more than guess without the actual code though

Comment: you are passing a float array to a function expecing a int array. Also, if you want to pass just the array to read and/or modify its contents, all you need to do is `oid funkcia_e( int *pole_cien, int* dlzka_pola_cien, bool v_bolo_vykonane )` and then call it as `funkcia_e(pole_cien, &dlzka_pola_cien, v_bolo_vykonane)`

Comment: thank you @Nadir, your solution helped. How shall I write to the array now (from within funkcia_e) or realloc that array (also within funkcia_e)

Comment: The current way allows you to modify the array. You can access it using brackets as `pole_cien[index]`. if you want to realloc the array itself, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer, in other words, `void funkcia_e( int **pole_cien...` and call it as `funkcia_e(&pole_cie,...`

Comment: Please check the Callee and caller signature. It’s type mismatch that’s what compiler complaints about.